# AzCopy Copy from fileshare to blob with file path included in the blob name

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Can I copy a directory from a share with subdirectories so that blob name would have the path name?

\\testshare\July\File1.txt

\\testshare\May\File1.txt

\\testshare\June\File3.txt

\\testshare\June\Week3\File3.txt

In the blob container, I want to have

July/File1.text

May/File1.text

June/File3.txt

June/Week3/File3.txt

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, AZCopy does that by default.

AzCopy /Dest:https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/files /Source:C:\myfolder /DestKey:xzxzxzxzzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxz== /S